# How to get the item values of CollectionView items with button action iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My implementation is like CollectionViews in tableview cells like in the picture. I have one button in that button action I need get the items of all CollectionView cells of particular index. any idea to achieve this in simple way.
[Check this for image of my implementation CollectionViews in tableview cells and need to get the items of particular rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StSpc.png)

Comment: Get it from your data, not from the cells.

Comment: Please provide some idea how to get it from code.

Comment: You need to provide a better description of what you're doing, and what you're *trying* to do. You say *"I have one button"* but your image doesn't show a button. You also say *"like CollectionViews in tableview cells"* ... are those actually Collection Views, or does it just *look* like it? How are you providing data to those cells? Are the numbers you've shown going to change based on user input? If so, how is that happening? Please review [ask].